# How should I structure/pass my data or actions in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am transforming my defaultState (my whole reducer) like this right now:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

import { SIGN_UP_STEP, RESET_SIGN_UP } from '../actions/sign-up';

const defaultState = {
  ui: {
    loading: false
  }, metadata: {
    step: 1,
    code: null
  },
  data: {
    name: null,
    email: null,
    password: null,
    number: null,
    access_token: null
  }
}

export default function signUpReducer(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case SIGN_UP_STEP:
    return _.merge({}, state, action.data)
  case RESET_SIGN_UP:
    return defaultState;
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

and my actions right now like this

```
import request from 'axios';
import _ from 'lodash';

const BACKEND_ROOT = process.env.API_ROOT || 'http://localhost:3000';

export const SIGN_UP_STEP = 'SIGN_UP_STEP';
export const RESET_SIGN_UP = 'RESET_SIGN_UP';

export function signUpStep(data) {
  return {
    type: SIGN_UP_STEP,
    data
  }
}

...
```

But now I'm thinking how I should structure or how should I do this. If I should do format from sending from the component to action or from action to reducers.

Like, should I do it like this:

```
// component
const signUpAction = SignUpActions.signUpStep({
  step: 2,
  name: this.refs.name.value,
  email: this.refs.email.value,
  password: this.refs.password.value
});
dispatch(signUpAction);

// action
export function signUpStep(data) {
  return {
    type: SIGN_UP_STEP,
    {
      metadata: {
        step: data.step
      },
      data: data.data
    }
  }
}
```

Or format it first before sending it?

```
// component
const signUpAction = SignUpActions.signUpStep({
  metadata: {
    step: 2,
  },
  data: {
    name: this.refs.name.value,
    email: this.refs.email.value,
    password: this.refs.password.value
  }
});
dispatch(signUpAction);

// action
export function signUpStep(data) {
  return {
    type: SIGN_UP_STEP,
    data
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommended the first one. Keep your action call as simple as possible, perform all the necessary logic in your action. But basically it's just up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Kai in the comments, but to take it slightly further I prefer the actions to show contract.

```
export function signUpStep(name, email, password, ...args){
  return { type: SIGN_UP_STEP,
    metadata: {
      step: 2
    },
    data: {name, email, password, ..args}
  }
}

// to call
signUpStep("John", "john@example.com", "Pass1", "doej");

// to access "doej" parameter from function
const githubId = args[0];
```

Obviously this is all personal preference, but in the section above you are now exposing an explicit contract of the necessary fields that are expected by the action without reading the action.

Comment: I see. Just in case, what does explicit contract mean? Also, `...args` are the remaining whatever variables passed right? How is it used?

Comment: The contract helps show how the function is intending to be used. Yes, `...args` will bundle all other parameters into a single object. I will update the answer to show how it would be called.